# PHP with WAMP Server submit unachieved

Tags: php, localhost, wamp, submit, publish

I have written a simple php file for my new site following what I've seen in a tutorial. Unfortunately, when I publish the site on my local host, the submit button does not appear in the page. Can you help me?

Here is the code:

//new_entry.php

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","youtube");
?>
if(isset($POST['submit'])){
    echo $str=$POST['str'];
} 

<form method="post">
    <input type="textbox" name="str" required/>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"/>
</form>
```

//index.php

```
<?php
    define ("SITE_ADDR", "http://localhost/CharleroiFurniture");
    $site_title = "CharleroiFurniture" ;
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="wtf-8>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width-device-width">
        <title><?php echo $site_title; ?> </title>
        <link ref="stylesheart" type="text/css" href="./main.css"></link>
    </head>
<body>
    <div  fd="wrapper">
        <div fd="tmp_header">
            <div fd="nav">
                <a href="<?php echo SITE_ADDR;?>/new_entry.php" New Entry</a>
        </div>
        <div fd="logo">
            <hI><a href="<?php echo SITE_ADDR;?>">CharleroiFurniture/a></hI>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div fd="main" class="shadow-box" >
        <div fd="content">
            <form action="" method="GET" name="">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type="text" name="k"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div> 
    </div>
    <div fd="footer"></div>
</div>
</body> 
</html>
```

1. I already tried to replace the submit by a button
2. I tried to call the class submit:
3. I tried to announce html code and to close the html section

The goal is to generate the submit button or any other button while it is intended to make a submit form

Comment: In `if(isset($POST['submit']))` it should be `$_POST`.. same in the line below `echo $str=$POST['str'];`

Comment: There is no input with a type of textbox so `<input type="textbox"` change that to `type="text"`

Comment: You also need to pay more attention to the detail of the tutorials you follow `<meta charset="wtf-8>` <<< Shoudl be `<meta charset="UTF-8">`

Comment: There is no `<hI>` tag, there is a `<h1>` though. Again attention to detail

Comment: And again `CharleroiFurniture/a>` should be `CharleroiFurniture</a>` with the `<` in place

Comment: You also have a dangling `</div>`. Good code indentation and layout ___is for life, not just for Christmas___ and would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Thank you very much. For My defense, I must say I used to copy the code using a small window where it was written so small. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So looks like you have 2 pages. index.php has the form and new_entry.php is the form handler. You need to make a couple of changes for this to work.

index.php

- point the form to its handler by setting the action to "new_entry.php"
- the handler is expecting a POST request, so change the method to "POST"
- add the submit button to this form

```php
<form action="new_entry.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="str">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

new_entry.php

- check if the form was submitted by checking if the method is POST
- output the posted value
- Output the form again so you can post something else

```php
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    echo $_POST['str'];
}

<form action="new_entry.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="str">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you. I do not code php usually. I was here doing some kind of reverse engineering trying to code thanks to coding notions of C# and a tutorial